# Laravel 4 - Username not being passed on in URL

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to get into Laravel 4 and am having a problem with editing users I have created. So far I have controllers, views, and routes to show a user and then edit the user by clicking the "Edit" button but when I click the submit button I keep getting a  NotFoundHttpException and the "Crash/Error" orange and white Laravel screen. I did, however, notice that the URL changes from showing the username (ex - public/users/av1/edit - with av1 being the username) to only saying {username} (ex -public/users/{username}/edit). I am still new to Laravel but my thought is that I'm not passing the username along properly but I know that it could also be the Controller or route as well. I have tried removing and changing sections of code and have found that if I remove the code from the Controller I still get a URL with {username} but I at least don't get the "Crash/Errors" screen. If anyone could help explain where I am going wrong it would be very much appreciated!

Here is my view:

```
@extends('layout.main')

    @section('content')
        {{ Form::model($user, array('route'=>'user-edit-post')) }}
        <div>
            {{ Form::label('username', 'Username:')}}
            {{ Form::text('username') }}
            @if($errors->has('username'))
                {{ $errors->first('username') }}
            @endif
        </div>

        <div>
            {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:')}}
            {{ Form::password('password') }}
            @if($errors->has('password'))
                {{ $errors->first('password') }}
            @endif
        </div>

        <div>
            {{ Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Confirm Password:')}}
            {{ Form::password('password_confirmation') }}
            @if($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                {{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}
            @endif
        </div>

        <div>
            {{ Form::submit('Edit User') }}
        </div>
    @stop
```

My User Controller functions that relates to editing:

```
public function getEdit($username){
        $user = User::where('username', '=', $username);

        if($user->count()) {
            $user = $user->first();

            return View::make('users.edit')
                    ->with('user', $user);
        } else {
            return App::abort(404);
        }           
    }

    public function postEdit($username){

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
            array(
                'first_name'                => 'required|max:20',
                'last_name'                 => 'required|max:20',
                'email'                     => 'required|max:50|email',
                'username'                  => 'required|max:20|min:3',
                'password'                  => 'required|min:6',
                'password_confirmation'     => 'required|same:password'
            )
        );

        if($validator->fails()){
            return Redirect::route('user-edit')
                ->withErrors($validator);
        } else {
            /*Edit User*/
            $user               = User::whereUsername($username)->first();
            $password           = Input::get('password');
            $user->password     = Hash::make($password); 
            $user->first_name   = Input::get('first_name');
            $user->last_name    = Input::get('last_name');
            $user->email        = Input::get('email');
            $user->username     = Input::get('username');

            /*password is the field $password is the variable that will be used in the password field*/

            if($user->save()){
                return Redirect::route('home')
                    ->with('global', 'The password has been changed.');
        }
        return Redirect::route('home')
                ->with('global', 'The password could not be changed.');

        }

    }
```

And lastly my Routes:

```
/*Edit users (GET)*/
    Route::get('users/{username}/edit', array(
        'as'    => 'user-edit',
        'uses'  => 'UserController@getEdit'
    ));

/*Edit Order (POST)*/
                Route::post('/orders/{orders}/edit', array(
                    'as'    => 'order-edit-post',
                    'uses'  => 'OrderController@postEdit'
                ));
```

Comment: Sorry, added the wrong POST route earlier - here is the correct one: 


Route::post('/users/{username}/edit', 
array(
 'as'  => 'user-edit-post',
 'uses'  => 'UserController@postEdit',
    ));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('route'=>'user-edit-post')) }}
```

To

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('route'=>array('user-edit-post', $user->username))) }}
```

Your route need additional parameters, so you need supply your parameters with your route name when binding model to form.

Yep, after reading the comment. I found the reason of your trouble here is the redirect in the `postEdit` function:

Change:

```
if($validator->fails()){
    return Redirect::route('user-edit')
                     ->withErrors($validator);
}
```

Into

```
if($validator->fails()){
    return Redirect::route('user-edit', $username)
                     ->withErrors($validator);
}
```

Again, your route need parameters. When the validation fails, you have been redirected to a wrong URL.

Comment: I tried but the URL still comes up as public/users/{username}/edit

Comment: Like this: /*Edit User (POST)*/
    Route::post('/users/{username}/edit', array(
     'as'  => 'user-edit-post',
     'uses'  => 'UserController@postEdit',
     'username' => $username,
    ));  

?

Comment: No, your route only need declaring like this: `Route::post('/users/{username}/edit', array( 'as' => 'user-edit-post', 'uses' => 'UserController@postEdit'));`

Comment: Huh, can you inspect element with your browser and see the `action` attribute of the form? You can also try to echo the value of `URL::route('user-edit-post', $user->username)` inside your form.

Comment: The submit button's action is "public/users/av1/edit"

Comment: And when I echo the value of the route the end comes out as "public/users/av1/edit" as well. Any clue why I'm losing the username when I send it through my user-edit-post route?

Comment: Also the validator isn't even catching mistakes, so I don't think the page is even getting that far.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50057/discussion-between-hieu-le-and-gv0029)

Comment: You sir, are my hero.